# ORA-01877: string is too long for internal buffer

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle11g, relational-database

I'm Trying to insert a row into ORDER table with a structure as follows:

[image]

However when using this insert statement:

```
INSERT INTO "ORDER" (
    CUSTREQDATE,
    CUSTREQTIME,
    DATEPICKEDUP,
    TIMEPICKEDUP,
    ACTUALDATEDELIVERED,
    ACTUALTIMEDELIVERED,
    DELIVEREDFLAG,
    RESTAURANTID,
    CUSTOMERID,
    DRIVERID,
    CUSTADDRESSID
) VALUES (
    TO_DATE('01/08/2017', 'DD/MM/YYYY'),
    TO_DSINTERVAL('0 19:00:00'),
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    'X',
    5,
    1,
    10,
    1
);
```

It throws me the error:

> ORA-01877:  string is too long for internal buffer

I know its not my Date fields because I can insert dates on my other tables successfully using the `TO_DATE` statement.

Could it be my `TO_DSINTERVAL` statement?

Comment: Not sure, about why you getting the error, I couldn't replicate the same in my system, I am able to insert via `TO_DSINTERVAL` with the table you have. Also, why are you en-quoting your table name ?

Comment: Sql developer wouldnt let me insert on ORDER or create the order table without enclosing it in double quotes. Hmm

Comment: `ORDER` is reserved word in sql, you cannot use it for naming without enlosing.

Answer (score 1):

`'X'` that you're trying to insert probably requires more than 1 byte (depending on your encoding).

Try changing byte to char:

```
ALTER TABLE "ORDER"
MODIFY(DELIVEREDFLAG CHAR (1 CHAR))
```

Or you can just increase `DELIVEREDFLAG` size:

```
ALTER TABLE "ORDER"
MODIFY(DELIVEREDFLAG CHAR (2 BYTE))
```

Comment: I had another flag field in another table that had the same rule and did accept the 'X' with no problems. Will try this nevertheless and report back